# How to check correctly in server json response?

Tags: android

I'm a very beginner in android, I want to write a simple application to check server json returned to my phone,server returns to me this son:

```
    ""OKPOST""
```

I want to write this simple if condition:

```
if (result==""OKPOST"") do something...
```

But I get error in if block in double quotation ,how can i solve that?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want check string, do like this:

```
if (result.contentEquals("\"OKPOST\"")) {
// do something...
}
```